# sensible, sensitive, and sentient

Tags: differences

Despite the apparently same meanings of the three words (which I looked up in Wiktionary), I would like to know if my interpretation is correct regarding their differences.

"sensible" is used to describe a person who can be perceived and understood by other people.

"sensitive" is used to describe a person who can perceive other people or things.

I am not sure about "sentient". Is it the same as "sensible" or "sensitive"?

Comment: The definitions in Wiktionary are divided into numbered senses, which are listed chronologically for *sensible* and *sensitive* (but not for *sentient*). All three are etymologically related, so it's not surprising that they started out with related meanings, and if you only read the first sense Wiktionary lists for each word, you might be tricked into thinking they're still very similar. But they've diverged significantly since they came into being, and they aren't really that closely related anymore. Do you think you could do a little more research and come back if you're still confused?

Comment: I did some research for a while, not just now. I brought this up, because I encountered the same question again. I tried to abstract some shorter principles that are easier to remember and apply than the many numbered meanings of the words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you find definitions that show the words to be synonyms? They are hardly even close:

> [sen·tient](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sentient)
>
> 1. Having sense perception; conscious: "The living knew themselves just sentient puppets on God's stage" (T.E. Lawrence).
> 2. Experiencing sensation or feeling.
>
> [sen·si·tive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sensitive)
>
> 1. Capable of perceiving with a sense or senses.
> 2. Responsive to external conditions or stimulation.
> 3. Susceptible to the attitudes, feelings, or circumstances of others.
> 4. Quick to take offense; touchy.
> 5. Easily irritated: sensitive skin.
> 6. Readily altered by the action of an agent: film that is sensitive to light.
> 7. Registering very slight differences or changes of condition. Used of an instrument.
> 8. Fluctuating or tending to fluctuate, as in price: sensitive stocks.
> 9. Of or relating to classified information: sensitive defense data; holds a sensitive position in the State Department.
>
> [sen·si·ble](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sensible)
>
> 1. Perceptible by the senses or by the mind.
> 2. Readily perceived; appreciable.
> 3. Having the faculty of sensation; able to feel or perceive.
> 4. Having a perception of something; cognizant: "I am sensible that a good deal more is still to be done" (Edmund Burke). See Synonyms at
>    aware.
> 5. Acting with or exhibiting good sense: a sensible person; a sensible choice.

In everyday usage, *sentient* means conscious or self-aware (in the sci-fi world, it is often used to differentiate intelligent life forms from animals). *Sensitive* means being receptive to stimuli/ For example, *I have sensitive eyes and bright lights bother me*. *Sensible* means reasonable, possessing common sense.

The three words share common origins but do not really have similar, let alone identical, meanings.

Answer (score 1):

To steal your method for defining, I would say:

"sentient" is used to describe a person who has the capacity to perceive and understand.

[Oxford's definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sentient) - able to perceive or feel things

Comment: So is sentient same as sensitive not as sensible?

Comment: I would be hesitant to equate sensitive and sentient, primarily because their common usage differs.  As a native American English speaker, I typically hear sensitive used in reference to one who is *particularly* [empathetic.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/empathy)  Sentient, on the other hand, is typically used to differentiate between beings capable of "thought" and beings incapable of "thought."